# Babel does not transpile imported modules from 'node_modules'

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I got a problem with transpiling imported modules from `node_modules`. Babel for some reason doesn't transpile imported module from `node_modules`, but transpile modules imported from `src`.

Here is an example repo: https://github.com/NikitaKA/babeltest

**main.js**

```
// result code contains const and let, but it shouldn't. :(
```

**index.js**

```
import qs from 'query-string; // not transpiled
import lib from './lib' // transpiled

const query = qs.parse(window.location.search);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 39
      }
    }],
    ["@babel/preset-stage-1", {
      "modules": false,
      "decoratorsLegacy": true,
      "pipelineProposal": "minimal"
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-constants",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is usually how things should be. Is there a particular reason you want to transpile the already distribution-ready modules that live in `node_modules`?

Comment: By the way, the example repo is missing `webpack-cli`/`webpack-command`, so the `start` command doesn't work OOTB.

Comment: oops, it seems that I have installed webpack-cli globally.

Comment: @AKX the lib in node_modules use `const`, I want to compile it to `var` to support lower broswer

Answer (score 10):

The solution in this case is to transpile the module again, this can be done by modifying the `exclude` property in your webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(es6-module|another-es6-module)\/).*/,
},
```

Modules `es6-module` and `another-es6-module` will no longer be ignored by webpack and will be transpiled with the rest of your source code.

See the [GitHub issue on the webpack project](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031).

Tested with `webpack@3.12.0`, `babel-core@6.26.3` and `babel-core@6.26.3`

Answer (score 6):

To expand upon my comments:

You really don't want to transpile all of `node_modules` – it'll take a long time, and most of the code there should already be ES5 (unless they're actually ES6 modules, in which case the ES6 entry point is announced as `"module"` in the `package.json` manifest).

`query-string@6.x` *isn't*, and it says so in [its README](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string):

> This module targets Node.js 6 or later and the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. If you want support for older browsers, use version 5: `npm install query-string@5`.

Comment: I understood what did you mean. You right and I shouldn't transpile distributed modules, especially if there is version for older versions which support older browsers (I didn't check, my bad). But it seemed strange to me that you cannot compile modern libraries to ES5, what if there are no older versions? In my case it was necessary to compile project under the old browser and this is luckthat  it's only one external library in the project and it have ES5 analogue :).

Comment: anyway, is there a way to transpile the module from `node_modules`?

Comment: from [webpack issue 2031](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031#issuecomment-219040479): 
`{ test: /\.js$/,   exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(MY-MODULE|ANOTHER-ONE)\/).*/, },`

Comment: From what i understand OP _wants_ to transpile node_modules (or at least specific non-conformant modules).   You mentioned yourself that modules `should already be ES5`  (key word `should`). So sometimes modules are not properly packaged and we may need to manually transpile them... Your answer does not answer that question

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vue, there is a simple solution. Just list your module in `transpileDependencies`:

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
   publicPath: '',
   outputDir: 'www',
   transpileDependencies: [
    'query-string'
  ],
}
```

Comment: Super nice! This also works for packages added with lerna