# ThreeJS module is not transpiled by Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js, babeljs, transpiler

Im using Three.js as a module, transpiling a code using Babel, packing with WebPack. The problem is that even all the other code is properly transpiled, the three.js module is not and still contains ES6 syntax. Which causes problems in IE11.

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
        "@babel/preset-env" , {
        "targets": {
            "ie": "11"
        }
    }]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-classes"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        //exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
...
```

Here I commented out to exclude the node_module folder, but even with that the problem still persists

Any idea what is wrong and how I could get transpiled Threejs module? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

In the webpack config, set the exclude property like this:
`exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(three)\/).*/,`.

This forces babel to transpile three no matter what.
Reference: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56428646/10847554)

Cheers

Comment: Hi, a bit old but I recently ran into a similar problem with yarn2. Do you know by any chance how to exclude three in yarn2 that does not have node_modules anymore?